# Dart Warnings in VS Code

Tags: json, dart, exception, visual-studio-code, dart-pub

I would like to remove underlines that shows up when I'm trying to code.
Is anyone here knows the solution >?

(#Omit type annotations for local variables...

[image])

Answer (score 0):

You can leave off the type annotation if the inference is correct, and that's what Dart central encourages you to do.  Just `var` or `final`.